# MDT installs to drive letter V

Tags: mdt, mdt-2013

I have an issue where MDT 2013 Update 2 installs to drive letter V as opposed to C. In the Past, my deployment share has always deployed to C.

I am using a LTI, no SCCM is used in the deployment. The task sequence gives no options to select a drive letter, it just says it will select the first available drive letter.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your unattended.xml,  task sequence and step that installs/applies your OS/image? Thanks!

Comment: Update: During the MDT process, the image is applied to the v: drive, but in the end the OS runs off of the c: drive. Looks like it was a non-issue.

Comment: Awesome! Can you delete your question or post an answer to it so it can be closed? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Update: During the MDT process, the image is applied to the v: drive, but in the end the OS runs off of the c: drive. Looks like it was a non-issue.